# c# .NET LINQ Query and returning a count for Excel to Json

Tags: c#, json, excel, linq

I currently use the [ClosedXml](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) to open up an Excel file, and Im wanting to convert the rows/cells into a json string which looks like this (or this format):

```
{"listOfRows":
  [
    {"column0":"test", "column1":"test1", "column2":"test1", },
    {"column0":"test", "column1":"test1"}
  ],
"rowNumber":1}
```

The column number needs to increment and thats where im struggling. I currently have the following linq query:

```
var test = from row in workSheet.Rows()
           select new
           {
               listOfRows = from cell in row.Cells()
                            select new
                            {
                                column = cell.Value,
                            },
               rowNumber = row.RowNumber()
            };
```

which as you will work out doesnt increment my column. Can anyone help with the curly one?

Comment: How accurately must your json be? Is it fine if each column in a row is an object itself with column index and value as properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this more like you expected it?

Linqs `.Select()` method also supports an indexer:

```
var test = workSheet.Rows().Select((row, i) =>
   new
   {
      listOfRows = row.Cells().Select((cell, j) => {
          var obj = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
          obj.Add($"column{j}", cell.Value);

          return obj;
      }),
      rowNumber = i
   });
```

Now to the expando object (let me explain a bit):

It is only available through the DLR (dynamic language runtime) and allows you to add properties at runtime.

The first iterations most inner code is about equal to:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.column0 = cell.Value;

return obj;
```

However, then you can't control the property name with the indexer, hence using the `obj.Add($"column{j}", cell.Value);` syntax in my answer.

For the sake of completness, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx)'s the MSDN link.

Comment: Seems closer. As in theory itll work. But it doesnt compile? So close!!! Thank you for all your help. So appreciated

Comment: it was nissing a paranthesis, so yea ... does it compile now?

Comment: No unfortunately not. Is it because the select doesnt have an object?

Comment: @user1112324 can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

I would break the problem out by first writing an extension method ...

```
public static dynamic ToObject(this IDictionary<string, object> source)
{
    dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
    source.ForEach(i => result[i.Key] = i.Value);
    return result;
}
```

If you then build each row out to a dictionary then ToObject() each dictionary a simple json convert on the final test object should suffice ...

```
var test = new { 
   listOfRows =  workSheet.Rows()
     .Select(r => {
        var row = r.Cells().Select((c,i) => new { Key = $"Column{i}", Value = c.Value })
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
           .ToObject();
        row.rowNumber = r.RowNumber();
        return row;
   };
```